# matlabcontrol not sending eval to MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab

I have a strange problem with [matlabcontrol](https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/).  I am using MATLAB R2013b and the latest matlabcontrol jar available from the source site.  I have the following piece of code in my program.

```
MatlabProxyFactoryOptions proxyOptions = new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder().setHidden(false).build();
proxFactory = new MatlabProxyFactory(proxyOptions);
    try
    {

        matlabProxy = proxFactory.getProxy();
        String matCmd = "load('" + setupFile + "');";
        matlabProxy.eval(matCmd);
        matlabProxy.eval("a = 2;");
    }
```

The above code will execute if I run it release.  In debug, if I try to step over the `eval` commands, they do not get passed to MATLAB it seems.  I keep the `matlabProxy` object for use in other parts of the program.  Even in release, this block executes correctly on MATLAB, but the other parts of the code that make calls to `eval` do not.  This is a piece of a server, thus when the other `eval`s are called it is after a waiting period for information through the socket.

Any info on why the debug stepping would cause the `eval` to not be sent to MATLAB would be a great help.  Thanks.